# nginx url rewriting between 2 domain names

Tags: wordpress, nginx, url-rewriting

Got an issue with URL rewrite under nginx. Actually I have a main domain name **dns1.com** which is pointing a webserver with a WordPress installation (permalink = /%category%/%postname%/). I've created this page **dns1.com/forum/forumname1**.

I also have a domain name **forumname1.com** and I want this one to be pointed to the content of **dns1.com/forum/forumname1**. The issue is that I don't know how to display the result of **dns1.com/forum/forumname1** with only **forumname1.com** in the bar address :( Actually it works when I go to **forumname1.com/forum/forumname1** but this URL is pretty redundant :/ I should make this parameter "/forum/forumname1" hidden but how?

Here is my nginx serverblocks :

```
server{
          server_name dns1.com;
          root /var/www/dns1.com;
          location = /forum/forumname1 {
                    rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://forumname1.com permanent;
          }
}

server{
          server_name forumname1.com;
          root /var/www/dns1.com;
          location = / {
                  ### Rewriting rule HERE but which one?
          }
}
```

Thank you :)

Comment: `rewrite ^ /forum/forumname1` would perform an internal redirect which would serve the desired location without changing the URL bar.

Comment: The fact is I want to display the content of "dns1.com/forum/forumname1" by accessing only "forumname1.com" :/

Comment: Place the rewrite I suggested in place of your comment and it will, won't it?

Comment: It moves to forumname1.com/forum/forumname :/

Comment: Actually I want to make invisible/hidden "forum/forumname" but having the result of it!

Comment: It sounds like your *hidden*  location is issuing a 301 redirect which will expose it. Without seeing the entire server block it's difficult to advise further.